# moving object in unity from a point A to point B no matter what the original position of the object is

Tags: c#, unity, movement

I'm moving a Game Object in unity from point A to point B no matter what the original position of the Game Object is.

Let us suppose that I have a Game Object at (0, 0, 0).

But I want to move that Game Object from (1, 1, 1) to (2, 2, 2).

How can I do this in C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the object's `Transform.position` to [Vector3.Lerp(Vector3 A, Vector3 B, percent completion](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)

Comment: Why not just set it? I don't think he's looking for Lerp.

Comment: Its a bit ambiguous but I actually read it that he does want to lerp over time from A to B